# calling function pointer create error of double redeclared symbol

Tags: c

**edit: problem happens because I declare the variable after the function **
so I am getting this error when calling function pointer:

```
redeclared as different kind of symbol
asmlinkage long (*orig_read122) (unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count);
```

but this symbol is not define twice infect when I remove the call to the pointer the error removed

my code

```
asmlinkage long (*orig_read122) (unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count);
int my_function(unsigned int reg,char __user *which,size_t count)
{ 
 orig_read122(reg,which,count);
}
```

Comment: We hope you assigned orig_read122 some function. Isn't it?

Comment: Is it a pseudo code as terminating ";" is missing in my_function ?

Comment: @RachidK. no sorry I delete it when writeing part of the code here

Comment: @EOF I think I did is it have anything to do with this error

Comment: Where's the other definition of orig_read122?

Comment: @Joshua as I said there isnt any other definition the error coming up only when I add the call

Comment: There is. It's probably declared as function and you're trying to declare it is pointer to function.

Comment: @Joshua well I rename this pointer many time that why there is 112 in the end so noway there is another function

Comment: Is it declared w/o asmlinkage somewhere? Compiler errors are seldom wrong.

Comment: Oh yes, if you call it before declaring it, that's an implicit declaration.

Comment: @Joshua thanks it solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

So the problem was something like this:

```
int some_function()
{
    char buf[1];
    orig_read122(0, buf, 1);
}

asmlinkage long (*orig_read122) (unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count);
int my_function(unsigned int reg,char __user *wich,size_t count)
{ 
 orig_read122(reg,wich,count);
}
```

Where `org_read122` is used before being defined. Implicit declaration is a terribly bad practice and usually leads to undefined behavior (`int` and `void *` aren't the same size anymore), but in this cae the code didn't compile because the implicit declaration didn't match the explicit declaration.

The solution is to move the definition of `orig_read122` to the top of the file.

Comment: If the calls had been done like this : (* orig_read122)(0, buf, 1), the compiler would have raised an error saying that orig_read122 is undeclared.